# Insert List in Order Entity Framework

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework

I have a sorted list on column2 and want to insert data in specific order

```
    someRandomList.ForEach(x =>
{
    var data = new CSharpObject{
    column1 = x.column1,
    column2 = x.column2,
    column3 = x.column3
    };
    _unitOfWork.Repository<CSharpObject>().Insert(data)
});

//Definition for Insert method    
public void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
  _dbset.Add(entity);
}
```

The table CSharpObject has primary key on column1 and elements are sorted by column2 in List.
But after the record insertion it is neither sorted by PrimaryKey (GUID Column) nor by column2.
Every time records are inserted in random order.
Is there any thing we can do?

Comment: Firstly the order is nondeterministic when you do this in EF. Secondly, why are you using the repository pattern over EF, that would be an instant fail in my class... lastly, if you want to maintain order, use a bulk insert tool that will maintain order, or save them one at a time, or specify an order field. Lastly2, why do you care if its in order, its a database, you order on the query. However if you do need them in the exact order, see above

Comment: Not the "generic repository" antipattern again. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work. A DbSet is already a repository. `DbSet` doesn't add anything to the database, `SaveChanges` does - it persists *all* pending changes, which is why DbContext is a UoW. Read [No need for Repository and Unit-oof-Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: What you want to do doesn't need a full ORM. You can use a micro-ORM like Dapper to just generate an INSERT from a list of objects.

Comment: @TheGeneral have you ever heard of something called decoupling? Good luck replacing your ORM if your codebase if full of EF references. EF implementes repository pattern. DBSet is but a repository. The same goes for you@Panagiotis Kanavos.